# gzipped MemoryStream to S3 bucket hashing incorrectly

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, hash, json.net, md5

I'm trying to serialize an object as JSON (newtonsoft.json), and store it in an S3 bucket in gzip compressed form. I want to use the MD5Digest property of PutObjectRequest to confirm successful transfer, but I'm having trouble getting the hash to calculate properly from the MemoryStream. I'm guessing it has to do with encoding.

```
BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(<access key>, <secret key>);
AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, <region>);

AmazonS3Client s3Client 
string md5Hash = null;
//Serialize JSON package to be uploaded to AWS
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
serializer.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include;
serializer.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto;
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    //Write JSON to memory stream through compression layer
    using (GZipStream zipStream = new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionLevel.Fastest, true))
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(zipStream))
    using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, <object to serialize>);
        writer.Flush();
    }
    //Store gzipped JSON package hash to confirm successful upload later
    using (MD5 md5 = MD5.Create())
    {
        byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(memoryStream);
        md5Hash = string.Concat(hash.Select(x => x.ToString("x2")));
    }
    //Reset memoryStream to start because ComputeHash has consumed it
    memoryStream.Position = 0;
    //Upload to AWS
    PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest();
    request.InputStream = memoryStream;
    request.Key = <file name>;
    request.BucketName = <bucket>;
    request.ContentType = "application/gzip";
    request.MD5Digest = md5Hash;
    PutObjectResponse response = s3Client.PutObject(request);
}
```

Comment: Presumably the MD5 hash you're providing is `d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e`, or the hash of an empty string.  You need to set the memory stream position to zero before you calculate the hash and before you upload as you are.

Answer (score 0):

There were 2 issues in my example.

Anon Coward correctly identified that the position of the MemoryStream needed to be reset.

The other problem is that PutObjectRequest.MD5Digest expects a base64 representation (even though AWS shows MD5 hash in Etag as hex).

The hash section of the code should look like this with both issues fixed

```
memoryStream.Position = 0;
using (MD5 md5 = MD5.Create())
{
    byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(memoryStream);
    md5Hash = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
}
```